# FLUTTER: Picked date not showing in Text controller

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I'm a beginner and I have this issue with the date picker I haven't been able to figure out: the picked date doesn't show in the text controller. The date picked is properly stored in selectedDate , but the text controller doesn't refresh, it keeps showing todays date. What is strange to me, is that the Time picker works fine. I've been comparing the two and don't see what the time picker does that the date picker doesn't.

Here is the full code :

```
class _DateTimePickerState extends State<DateTimePicker> {
  double _height;
  double _width;

  String _setTime, _setDate;

  String _hour, _minute, _time;

  String dateTime;

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 00);

  TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController();


  var dateValue = TextEditingController();

   Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;

      });
  }

  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(

      context: context,

      initialTime: selectedTime,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
            child: child,
          );
        },
    );
    if (picked != null)
      setState(() {

        selectedTime = picked;
        _hour = selectedTime.hour.toString();
        _minute = selectedTime.minute.toString();
        _time = _hour + ' : ' + _minute;
        _timeController.text = _time;
        _timeController.text = formatDate(
            DateTime(2019, 08, 1, selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute),
            [HH, ':', nn, " "]).toString();

      });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dateController.text = DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now());
    //_dateController.text = dateValue.text;


    _timeController.text = formatDate(
        DateTime(2019, 08, 1, DateTime.now().hour, DateTime.now().minute),
        [HH, ':', nn, " "]).toString();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    dateTime = DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text((globals["selected_person_name"])),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      body: Container(
        width: _width,
        height: _height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Choisir la Date',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20)
                ),

                InkWell(
                  onTap: ()  {
                   _selectDate(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: _width / 1.7,
                    height: _height / 9,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      enabled: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _dateController,
                      onSaved: (String valD) {
                        _setDate = valD;

                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          disabledBorder:
                          UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          // labelText: 'Time',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Choisir l\'heure',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20)
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _selectTime(context);

                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    width: _width / 1.7,
                    height: _height / 9,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      onSaved: (String val) {
                        _setTime = val;
                        },
                      enabled: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _timeController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          disabledBorder:
                          UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          // labelText: 'Time',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),

                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],

            ),
```

Comment: You aren't using selectedDate after assigning it and you are only using DateTime.now() for your _dateController

Comment: Thank you Andy for your reply, but how come the Timepicker works fine ?

Comment: If you look at your _selectTime method you will see that you are updating the _timeController value 

 _timeController.text = _time;
 _timeController.text = formatDate(DateTime(2019, 08, 1, selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute), [HH, ':', nn, " "]).toString();

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using selectedDate after assigning it and you are only using DateTime.now() for your _dateController. Try this instead

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
    firstDate: DateTime(2015),
    lastDate: DateTime(2101));
if (picked != null)
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;
    _dateController.text = DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate);
  });
```

}

Comment: Yes ok I see what you mean. Thing is I tried before to update the datecontroller.text here without any luck. I tried your code and it still wasn't working either. As I trust your skills more than mine, I closed and reopened Android Studio...and now it works ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Great! Glad it's working for you now. Remember, if you are making any changes related to state then make sure you use Hot Restart instead of Hot Reload. When you use Hot Reload it keeps the current state so that's why it may have not been working until you restarted Android Studio